# Bash completion for command line arguments and options

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI for my app in go and I would like to provide users with bash completions for options and arguments.

The API is the following `myapp [-f file] argument` andI would like to provide completion for both the option `-f` and the `argument`.

I wonder how I can distinguish between the following two scenarios:

- `myapp -f some_path<tab><tab>`
- `myapp -f some_file <tab><tab>`

In the first case the user is still typing the option and he/she would like to see candidates for the file option. In the second he/she finished typing and would like to see the candidates for the argument.

The problem is that in both cases the value of `os.Args` is identical and I can't distinguish between the two scenarios. Is there a way to access the invocation string?

One solution would be to use a separator like `--` between the option and the argument but I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution before I go down this path.

Comment: There is no "invocation string", your command line arguments are handed to you as a sting array (same as what os.Args shows you).  It's your shell (ie: bash) that sets up the args to pass to the app.  This issue is more of a bash question and not so much a go issue.

Comment: Yeah I imagined that. However the scenarios `myapp -f some_path<enter>` and `myapp -f some_file <enter>` receives the same `os.Args`. This means that the default bash behaviour is to strip the invocation string before chopping it into pieces and pass it to the app. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not doable without hacking bash.

Comment: As you already mentioned this is more of a bash issue. Take a look at [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html).